# Webservice without token in moodle

Tags: web-services, moodle

I am beginner for webservice. I am  writing a webservice in Moodle.

I would like to write one service for user sign up. In this case that user will not have any token or username+password.

How we can allow this user to call `core_user_createUsers` web service for sign up?

For other services I am using  this code:

```
$domainname = 'http://mydomain/moodle';

require_once('./curl.php');
$curl = new curl;

$authurl = $domainname .'/login/token.php?username=admin&password=Admin123$&service=shcs_services';
$resp = $curl->get($authurl);

if($resp)
{
    $resp = json_decode($resp);
    $authToken = $resp->token;
}

/// PARAMETERS
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php';


$params['wstoken'] = $authToken;
$params['wsfunction'] = 'core_user_createUsers';
$params['moodlewsrestformat'] = 'json';




$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->username = 'testusername';
$user1->password = 'Testpassword1%';
$user1->firstname = 'testfirstname1';
$user1->lastname = 'testlastname1';
$user1->email = 'testemail1@moodle.com';
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$user1->idnumber = 'testidnumber1';
$user1->lang = 'en';
$user1->theme = 'standard';
$user1->timezone = '-12.5';
$user1->mailformat = 0;
$user1->description = 'Hello World!';
$user1->city = 'testcity1';
$user1->country = 'au';
$preferencename1 = 'preference1';
$preferencename2 = 'preference2';
$user1->preferences = array(
    array('type' => $preferencename1, 'value' => 'preferencevalue1'),
    array('type' => $preferencename2, 'value' => 'preferencevalue2'));
$users = array($user1);
$params['users'] = $users;


$resp = $curl->post($serverurl, $params);
echo $resp;
```

in above code I would like to skip the  below part

```
$authurl = $domainname .'/login/token.php?username=admin&password=Admin123$&service=shcs_services';
$resp = $curl->get($authurl);

if($resp)
{
    $resp = json_decode($resp);
    $authToken = $resp->token;
}
```

so that I don't want to pass the value `$params['wstoken'] = $authToken;` to web service .

But it is not allowing me without the token. Here's the error I get:

```
{"exception":"moodle_exception","errorcode":"invalidtoken","message":"Invalid token - token not found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Token is the only way to connect the web service to with your app. It is must. As I am working  nowadays on web services and mobile app. So I experienced that token is the only way to validate the web services.  The first step to connect with web service by validating it. And you are not passing the token at all. So your validation is going to be failed. and you are getting this error.